# Converting table into different Format in excel

Tags: excel

[image: This is format in which the data that I have right now]

[image: I would like to change it to something like this]

I have data in the format shown in the first image with thousands of rows and different attributes. I would like for the data to be changed to a format in the 2nd image which would be easier to use and analyze. Are there any useful functions that could help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do the following (it is not easy as applying some function, but it works haha). My Excel is in Portuguese, but I hope the images help you.

- Copy the first column to another worksheet
- Delete duplicates [image: you can use this button]
- Insert a new line before the first line on the new worksheet
- Copy the second column of the original worksheet and paste it transposed - right click, transposed. Remember to just copy once each value. For example, in your case, just copy Name, Age, Height and Weight.
- Finally, it is possible to add a line to represent header for your original data. For example, the first column you can call `ID`, the second you call `Attribute` and  the third, `Value`. Then, you filter the colum `Attribute` by the first possibility - Name, in your case - and copy the column `Value` to the respective column on new worksheet. Then you filter by `Attribute` = Age and do the same. Do the same for all possibilities.

So, on the last step, the number of copy-paste is exactly the number of different values you have for your second column.

It is possible to do a VBA code to automate it, if you are going to do it frequently.

Answer (score 0):

**#1.** You can try to use `distinct` Formula to get your data index (column A)
or Use Remove Duplicate icon at Excel Ribbon.

**A2:A10** is the source list.
B1 is the cell above the first cell of the distinct list.

**#2.** Create Uniq Row (see my screencapture).

**#3.** You can use `vlookup` formula to match your data from sheet1 to sheet2.

[image: Excel Formula]